# Generating large NSString xml

Tags: objective-c, xml, ios, cocoa-touch, nsstring

I have a plist and i want to convert it to xml. The xml itself is going to be around 1.2mb in size. What the best way to generate this xml? Simply with a NSMutableString? I am just worried about the performance issues and wether there is a better way to generate xml.
Thanks

For those wondering, what I have right now is something like this:

```
NSString *xml = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<Sheet>%@</Sheet>", [self getSheetXMLString]];
```

and then, in `getSheetXMLString` method, i have more methods like above which drill down deep until the plist is fully transversed.

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What do you plan to do with the XML, if it is to output over a network or write to a file then instead of creating a NSString you could just write straight out to the network/file. If you plan to do manipulation if the XML you may want to consider libxml2, which is a C library included in iOS.

Comment: Um...I am uploading this to Amazon s3 servers. Doesn't necessarily need to be saved to disk. I will convert the string to NSData, then send it off. Also, i am using the iOS amazon sdk

Comment: Do whats easiest first, keeping in mind you may need to change it later. There is no point trying to solve a problem you don't know you have yet.